# How to create two columns based on diffrent values in order to avoid different chunks typing

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have an extended dataset that I would simplify like this:

```
BEZ <- c(0.5, 1.5)
var <- c(0, 1.5 )
bar <- c(3, 1.5)

BEZ1 <- c(0, 0.5)
var1 <- c(4, 4)
bar1 <- c(4, 4.5)

dat <- data.frame(BEZ, var, bar, BEZ1, var1, bar1)
dat
```

What I would like to do is to add two final columns reporting two sums:

1. the sum of every middle columns different from those `BEZ`;
2. the division between the first result and the sum of columns having `'BEZ'` in their names.

I have used this way:

```
scores = dat %>% 
  select(-starts_with('BEZ')) %>% 
  #replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  mutate(score_1 = rowSums(.), 
         score_2 = score_1/rowSums(dat %>% select(starts_with('BEZ'))))

new = cbind(dat, scores[, 5:6])
new
```

But I am looking for a way that would be easier and avoiding to create different chunks of code. Could you suggest any other different alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `across()` to select columns on which you want to do row-summing:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(score_1 = rowSums(across(!starts_with('BEZ'))),
         score_2 = score_1 / rowSums(across(starts_with('BEZ'))))

#   BEZ var bar BEZ1 var1 bar1 score_1 score_2
# 1 0.5 0.0 3.0  0.0    4  4.0    11.0   22.00
# 2 1.5 1.5 1.5  0.5    4  4.5    11.5    5.75
```

Comment: Thank you. In my real case, I would need to be more precise. Do you know whether I can add also `& ends_with()` in the second `across()` parenthesis?

Comment: @alias Yes you can! Any valid <tidy-select> syntax can be passed to `across()`.